# How to use e:force:navigateToUrl in lightning salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am exploring lightning experience and trying to leverage aura framework.
I have a button that calls an event `e.force:navigateToURL`.
Initially it gave an error :

> Action failed: c:LightningForceNavigateToURLDemo$controller$gotoURL
>   [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]

So I added aura dependency markup in the lightning component below.
So the error is gone, but still the redirect doesnot happen.
Am I missing anything?
Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code for quick reference:

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>
    <div id="aura-page">
        <div class="container">
            <ui:button label="gotoURL" press="{!c.gotoURL}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Client side controller:

```
({
    gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.gotoURL(component);
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "/006/o"
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Make sure you running in one.app container.This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to do it with directly from controller. No need to use in helper.
Also try to send event to helper as params.

```
gotoURL : function (component) {    
    $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({ 
       "url": "/006/o" 
    }).fire();
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it work @Shrey

Comment: I updated my code by sending event to helper. Still no luck. The button click do not redirect and no action is performed. Also the way I am trying to invoke this lightning app is : **.salesforce.com/c/myApp.app

Comment: @Shrey May be **force:navigateToURL** not directly working with application. Try to add your component using App builder and then see what happen.  Use this line in your component to make available in app builder `<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">`

Comment: Thanks Tarif. That answered my question. This means if we launch a lightning component / application directly from url, the lightning supported navigation methods do not work.

Comment: @Shrey If you are not in LEX or Salesforce1, you can just use window.location normally.